# Search Result webpart max displays 10 results regardless of settings

Tags: search, search-results, people-search

I have a search result webpart on one of my pages, which show the results of a people search (using a custom searchbar), but for some reason the maximum display of results are limited to show 10.

I search on a name which I know at least 20+ people in the corp. has, so it is confirmed that it should show more than 10. If I on the other hand search using the default sharepoint search bar, showing the results in the search center, it displays the correct amount of search results.

The result limit is set to 99 per page, but it only displays 10 regardless.
There is no paging when it only displays 10 as well. It completely cuts off all other results above 10.

Couldn't find visibly similar issues by googling. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have same issue so wouuld be very interested in a solution

Comment: Check your index to see how many profiles are really indexed. Also do a smilar search from search center to see how many total hits you get

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have exactly the same issue

Answer (score 2):

The limit is 50 records per page. Try 50 and it will display 50 per page. Changing it to 51 will revert to 10 results per page

Comment: This is the perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

The 'Results Per Page' is set to 10 by default. Please check the value by "modify webpart" tool pane.

Also, the paging is provided by another webpart called "Search Paging". Please check if it is present on your page.

Comment: I changed it to 99 and it still cut off the results at 10. Inserting Search Paging didn't help either :(

Answer (score 0):

From following article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg549981.aspx

Under Display Properties, in the Results Per Page box, type the number of results that you want to appear on a page before pagination is required. **The maximum is 50 results.** The default is 10 results. Increasing this number affects how quickly the user interface renders.

Answer (score 0):

Use designer to check the SOURCE CODE of the page itself.  Even though desginer might show no restrictions for the web part, the **`"<xsl:param name="MaximumRows">`10"`** will still be present.   Change the value to "0".

Also check the "**SharePoint:SPDataSource**" for the web part.  The "**DefaultValue**" might also be set to "10".  Change that to "0" also.

Just be very careful while editing the code.  Please make sure that you have a backup.